# iOS 15 beta RemoteIO unit outputs silent frames with stereo orientation

Tags: ios, core-audio, avaudiosession, audiounit, remoteio

Has anyone tried using RemoteIO unit on iOS 15 beta 3 with stereo orientation set on AVAudioSession? It emits silent audio frames on iOS 15 betas but works perfectly well on iOS 14. It works if stereo orientation is not enabled. This can be verified by running following sample code by Apple in stereo configuration:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/capturing_stereo_audio_from_built-in_microphones